# UIWebView image viewer in Xcode

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView linked to a dropbox link with different photos. Is there a way to hid a portion of the UIWebView to not show the top "dropbox bar" that shows? (Like in the image below)

Does anyone have any experience with the dropbox API? 
Would flickr be a better alternative?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not perfect solution but its a work around:

While loading your webpage (her dropbox page), call this javascript function "window.scrollTo(xpos, ypos);" here is tutorial for [scrollto](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp) method.

To call javascript function over webview, you require to

```
NSString* javascript = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.scrollBy(0, yPosValueHere);"];   
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:javascript];
```

Now where to call this method:

You can use [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods for this like:

```
– webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Hope this might help to solve your prob.

**Note:** User can scroll up manually and see that page.

Comment: Thank your for your input! I have decided that the best solution is not to have the images on a server, but to use UIScrollView with paging enabled and have the images stored inside the app directly. Thanks! :)